# Why I can see view1 after I triggering navigation to view2 (integration testing)

Tags: integration-testing, sapui5

I have some questions about integration testing (OPA5, sapui5): I have created simple project which has 2 views (View1.view.xml and View2.view.xml), and I have sap.m.Button on the first view. After I press this button I'll navigate to the second view. So I have implemented OPA5 tests to check this functionality. So now I'm simulating user's click at button and Navigation is working properly. But If I want to check visibility View1.view.xml after triggering navigation I will get "test passed" result! I guess that tests are executed asynchronously that is why I have had this results. And how can I catch moment when test will finish to execute next?

**UnexpectedbehaviorJourney.js**

```
QUnit.module("Unexpected behavior");
       opaTest("Why do I see View1.view after Navigation was pressed?",
      function (Given, When, Then) {

        // Arrangements
        Given.iStartMyApp();

        //Actions
        When.onTheAppView.iLookAtTheScreen().
            and.iPressNavigateButton();

        // Assertions
         Then.onTheAppView.iShouldSeeView1AfterTriggeringNavigation();
            // and.iTeardownMyAppFrame();
    });
```

**UnexpectedBehavior.js**

```
actions : {

                    iPressNavigateButton : function () {
                        return this.waitFor({
                            id : "idButton",
                            viewName : "View1",
                            actions: new Press(),
                            errorMessage : "Button control wasn't pressed"
                        });
                    }
                },

                assertions : {

                    iShouldSeeView1AfterTriggeringNavigation : function () {
                        return this.waitFor({
                            id : "idView1",
                            viewName : "View1",
                                success : function () {
                                ok( true, "Why I can see View1.view?");
                            },
                            errorMessage : "Navigation has worked as expected!"
                        });
                    }
                }
```

**View1.controller.js**

```
return Controller.extend("InvestigateOPA.controller.View1", {
        onPress: function() {
            this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("appView2");
        }
    });
```

Do you have any idea how can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the assertion be a check for View2 visibility?

else try something like below

nb. you can use Qunit and Sinon functions like a delay/timer or a native promise etc.

```
iShouldNotSeeView1AfterTriggeringNavigation : function () {
  return this.waitFor({
    id: "app",
    viewName: "App",
    check: function(oApp) {
         return oApp.getCurrentPage().getId() !== "__component0---View1"
    },
    success: function() {
        ok( true, "View1 not current page");
    },
    errorMessage: "Navigation has not worked as expected!"
});
```

Comment: Here is console.log:
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("View1");
undefined
so
    return !sap.ui.getCore().byId("View1");
unfortunately always true

Comment: ok, the views dont get destroyed, or set visible false, you can look into the oApp.getCurrentPage().getId() !== "__component0---View1" thats if you have an AppView

Comment: I have had interesting results! "oApp.getCurrentPage().getId()" return "__xmlview2", but I can see in the frame view1 ! I mean that button has executed navigation, my application has current page View2, but in the same time I can see View1 in the frame about one second and then View2 appears! So test that checks view1 control can pass! Now the question is how to chain visual element with functionality!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the one way to solve my problem is set "transition" property to "show":

```
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "show",
                "viewPath": "InvestigateOPA.view",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "app"
            },
```

In this case there is no visual delay when one view change another, so my OPA tests will work correctly.
p.s. thx a lot for your ideas!

Comment: GWT is based on user interactions, still not sure of the problem your attempting to solve